# "Not enough storage available to process this command" - Gradle with Android plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am having an issue when trying to build with Gradle with Android plugin. I am using Win 7 64 bit with 8GB RAM and Gradle 1.6 but "most of the time" when I tried to run "gradle build" from cmd,  I ran into this error "**CreateProcess error=8, Not enough storage is available to process this command**".
And the location of this error is at "**:mergeDebugResources**". My project directory is as follows:

*Hely | lib | actionbarsherlock | build.gradle (for android library)*

*Hely | build.gradle (for main app)*

The **first *build.gradle*** is

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
sourceSets {
    main {
 //default set up
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}}
```

And the **second *build.gradle*** is as :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
}}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile project(':lib:actionbarsherlock')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}}
```

I tried to increase the IRPStackSize but it did not help. The weird thing is the build did not fail all the time, in fact, I could build successfully "once per day".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my settings.gradle file in the project root from

```
include ':NightLamp', ':actionbarsherlock'
```

to

```
include ':NightLamp'
include ':actionbarsherlock'
```

and it seems to have fixed the issue for me... Weird, I know.